# how to create grails project in GGTS using version 3.1.6

Tags: grails, ggts, grails-3.1

I am new to Grail, I have created a small project in Grails 2.4.4 using the GGTS tool, but an unable to create the same project in grails version 3.1.6.

It's showing an error like the one below when I create a new poject under version 3.1.6:

```
couldn't find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ggts for grails 2 (although there are documentation and painful process to get it to work with grails 3. For grails 3 use https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ Community edition http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/gettingStarted.html

Answer (score 0):

GGTS officially doesn't have support for Grails 3.x but this 
[this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/10/eclipse-mars-grails-3-1-with-gradle-groovy-and-gsp-support.html) article can surely help.